# Control when data chunk flows through Node stream

Tags: node.js, stream

EDIT: I solved my own problem in this other post: [Extract binary values from stream with low memory consumption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55365136/extract-binary-values-from-stream-with-low-memory-consumption)

How does one precisely control the flow of a stream in NodeJS?

Take this code example from an express route:

```
const stream = require('stream');

class ControlStream extends stream.Transform{
    constructor(options){
        super(options);
    }

    _transform(chunk, enc, callback){
        this.push(chunk);
        callback();
    }
}

api.route("/stream").post((req, res) =>{
    let controlStream = new ControlStream({});
    req.pipe(controlStream);
});
```

In this example I am piping a request stream into a `ControlStream` instance which is just a subclass of `Transform`. The result is that data flows continuously through `ControlStream`.

I would like the ability to pause this data flow and instead be able to "request" each chunk of data.

For example:

```
const stream = require('stream');

class ControlStream extends stream.Transform{
    constructor(options){
        super(options);
    }

    _transform(chunk, enc, callback){
        this.push(chunk);
        callback();
    }

    getChunk(){
        //requests the next chunk of data to be sent into _transform
    }
}

api.route("/stream").post((req, res) =>{
    let controlStream = new ControlStream({});
    req.pipe(controlStream);

    controlStream.getChunk();
});
```

As far as I can see, the default implementation only allows me to "listen in" on the flow of data, but I can't seem to control **when** that data flows, or more importantly, **how much** data will flow.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: This would just be pausing req and then resuming it and the pausing it after a single chunk is delivered and then resuming it so that the process can repeat with the next chunk. I can see how to do it but I really want to question the reason it need to be done.

Comment: This is my reason why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55365136/extract-binary-values-from-stream-with-low-memory-consumption I'm trying to write a binary data parser that doesnt hold all the values in memory, however I need to control when a chunk enters the Transform stream in order to implement the logic I want afaik

Answer (score 0):

https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pause

The readableStream component of component does have a pause functionality, which is implemented by buffering the data and stopping any `'data'` events.

Comment: I'm aware of `.pause()` however how does one allow only a single chunk of data to pass through upon resuming? Also does this properly backpressure the streams? Or does the data just pile up in memory?

Comment: yes there is an internal back pressure mechanism in readable streams. You can modify the highWaterMark setting of both [readable](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_readablehighwatermark) and [writable](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_writablehighwatermark) streams

You can read a specific number of bytes of data by using the [readable.read method](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_read_size_1). The specific number of Bytes can be specified as the size arg.

Answer (score 0):

Since `express.Request` is a `ReadableStream`, what about async iteration (`for await`)?

```
// your function
async function process(...args) {
    //.....
}

// optional
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}


api.route("/stream").post(async (req, res) => {
    for await (const chunk of req) {
        await process(chunk); // do something with the chunk
        await sleep(3000); // you can also get a sleep if you need one
    }
});
```

I don't know about how much the data would flow, though

Comment: Thanks for your assistance! This does not backpressure the stream. The chunks sizes are irregular and go well beyond a single chunks buffer limit. This also isn't really what I need since I can't pause the stream (backpressure) and request the next chunk at will. This is basically just listening on the 'data' event